# numpy vectorize run pre-vectorized method more than the length of the input

Tags: numpy

I would expect when a function is vectorized by `np.vectorize` the total number of method run is the same as the input length. For example if the input is a scalar, the pre-vectorized method should only be run once. In a way, I expect a similar behaviour to `map(func, input_array)`.

However, running the example, you will see that the vectorized method **unnecessarily** ran `func` multiple times when the input is only scalar.

Does anyone know if I am using the method wrong? I have also opened a github [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/22054) as well.

```
import numpy as np
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

def func(x):
    logging.debug(f"Computation started")
    return x

func_v1 = np.vectorize(func)
func_v2 = np.vectorize(func_v1)
func_v1(1)  # logging shows the method func is ran twice
func_v2(1)  # logging shows the method func is ran four times.
```

Comment: This behavior is [documented](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#:~:text=If%20otypes%20is%20not%20specified,if%20your%20function%20is%20expensive.).

Comment: This also begs the question: why would you want to call a vectorized function with a scalar?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny If it is an array with length `n`, the total number of run would be `n+1`. And thank you for the pointer. I should have read the documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), the additional run is required when the `otype` is not provided. The additional run is to obtain the output type.